# Puppet Agent does not connect to master after installing Dashboard

Tags: ruby, passenger, puppet, dashboard

I had Puppet + Passenger installed and working.

Then I installed Dashboard on the puppet master.

I had to change the apache configuration file and replace the virtual host I had when I install Passenger with contain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName puppetsrv.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/puppet-dashboard/public/
    <Directory /usr/share/puppet-dashboard/public/>
        Options None
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /etc/httpd/logs/dashboard_error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /etc/httpd/logs/dashboard_access.log Combined
    ServerSignature On
</VirtualHost>
```

Now when I run on the agent :
 puppet agent  --no-daemonize --verbose

I got the error:

```
Notice: Starting Puppet client version 3.3.1 
Error: Failed to apply catalog: Connection refused - connect(2) 
Error: Could not send report: Connection refused - connect(2) 
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/agent.rb:89:in `exit': no implicit conversion from nil to integer (TypeError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/agent.rb:89:in `run_in_fork'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/agent.rb:86:in `fork'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/agent.rb:86:in `run_in_fork'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/agent.rb:41:in `run' .... .... .... .... ....
```

and have no nodes in the Dashboard on the puppet master.

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: the host or port that is configured on your client is not reachable from that server. that is why you are getting `Connection refused` errors. You need to find out where it wants to connect and reconfigure.

Comment: Now I think the problem is because I had to change the virtual host  definition in Apache configuration file. I have to define a different DocumentRoot. but I still dont know how to solve it. Is there someone that did it successfully?

Answer (score 0):

The original VirtualHost should actually be kept alongside the new one for Passenger. This is the [core concept](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#virtualhost) of virtual hosts.

To get the master working again, reintroduce the Passenger/SSL VHost on port 8140 like in [the example](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/passenger.html#create-and-enable-the-puppet-master-vhost).

If you can find a backup copy of the former apache config, that would make this much easier of course.